# numpy.polyfit gives useful fit, but infinite covariance matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to fit a polynomial to a set of data. Sometimes it may happen that the covariance matrix returned by `numpy.ployfit` only consists of `inf`, although the fit seems to be useful. There are no `numpy.inf` or 'numpy.nan' in the data!

Example:

```
import numpy as np
# sample data, does not contain really x**2-like behaviour, 
# but that should be visible in the fit results
x = [-449., -454., -459., -464., -469.]
y = [ 0.9677024,   0.97341953,  0.97724978,  0.98215678,  0.9876293]

fit, cov = np.polyfit(x, y, 2, cov=True)

print 'fit: ', fit
print 'cov: ', cov
```

Result:

```
fit: [  1.67867158e-06   5.69199547e-04   8.85146009e-01]
cov: [[ inf  inf  inf]
      [ inf  inf  inf]
      [ inf  inf  inf]]
```

`np.cov(x,y)` gives

```
[[  6.25000000e+01  -6.07388099e-02]
 [ -6.07388099e-02   5.92268942e-05]]
```

So `np.cov` is not the same as the covariance returned from `np.polyfit`. Has anybody an idea what's going on?

EDIT:
I now got the point that `numpy.cov` is not what I want. I need the variances of the polynom coefficients, but I dont get them if `(len(x) - order - 2.0) == 0`. Is there another way to get the variances of the fit polynom coefficients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [rustil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27230609/577088)'s answer says, this is caused by the bias correction applied to the denominator of the covariance equation, which results in a zero divide for this input. The reasoning behind this correction is similar to that behind [Bessel's Correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction). This is really a sign that there are too few datapoints to estimate covariance in a well-defined way.

How to skirt this problem? Well, this version of `polyfit` accepts *weights*. You could add another datapoint but weight it at epsilon. This is equivalent to reducing the `2.0` in [this formula](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L599) to a `1.0`.

```
x = [-449., -454., -459., -464., -469.]
y = [ 0.9677024,   0.97341953,  0.97724978,  0.98215678,  0.9876293]

x_extra = x + x[-1:]
y_extra = y + y[-1:]
weights = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, sys.float_info.epsilon]

fit, cov = np.polyfit(x, y, 2, cov=True)
fit_extra, cov_extra = np.polyfit(x_extra, y_extra, 2, w=weights, cov=True)

print fit == fit_extra
print cov_extra
```

The output. Note that the fit values are identical:

```
>>> print fit == fit_extra
[ True  True  True]
>>> print cov_extra
[[  8.84481850e-11   8.11954338e-08   1.86299297e-05]
 [  8.11954338e-08   7.45405039e-05   1.71036963e-02]
 [  1.86299297e-05   1.71036963e-02   3.92469307e+00]]
```

I am *very* uncertain that this will be especially meaningful, but it's a way to work around the problem. It's a bit of a kludge though. For something more robust, you could modify `polyfit` to accept its own `ddof` parameter, perhaps in lieu of the boolean that `cov` currently accepts. (I just [opened an issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5337) to suggest as much.)

A quick final note about the calculation of `cov`: If you look at the wikipedia page on [least squares regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#Parameter_errors_and_correlation), you'll see that the simplified formula for the covariance of the coefficients is `inv(dot(dot(X, W), X))`, which has a [corresponding line](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L593) in the numpy code -- at least roughly speaking. In this case, `X` is the [Vandermonde matrix](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L563), and the weights have already been [multiplied in](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L566). The numpy code also does some scaling (which I understand; it's part of a strategy to minimize numerical error) and multiplies the result by the norm of the residuals (which I don't understand; I can only guess that it's part of another version of the covariance formula).

Comment: The trick with the eps is quite nasty, but it actually works out! This is why I prefer your answer over the other answer given. This problem actually occurs when I split a dataset into subsets for piecewise fit. I'm now working on a custom function that I can fit to the full set via `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, which also gives a covariance matrix. Using the full set I should not run into a similar problem...

Comment: @jkalden, now that I understand the use case, this makes more sense. The fact that the results are reasonable within the piecewise fit helps to validate the result as well. I've never submitted a feature request to numpy before; I'll be interested to see if this use case persuades the developers that it's worth adding.

Comment: please drop a note here please once your feature request has been assessed by the numpy team.

Answer (score 2):

---

the difference should be in the degree of freedom. In the `polyfit` method it already takes into account that your degree is 2, thus causing:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  fac = resids / (len(x) - order - 2.0)
```

you can pass your `np.cov` a `ddof=` keyword (ddof = delta degrees of freedom) and you'll run into the same problem

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? Which ddof value should I use to get the same result? If I get you right, it should fail for all datasets where `(len(x) - order - 2.0) == 0`. That seems to be odd...

Comment: Actually, all I want to have is the variance estimates for each coefficient. I now got the point that `numpy.cov` is not the way to go, but how could I get the variances if `(len(x) - order - 2.0) == 0`?

Comment: @jkalden, can you add more datapoints? Part of the reason you're getting an infinite covariance matrix is that you're using a very small dataset. I feel pretty certain that the result wouldn't be that meaningful anyway.

Comment: @senderle: That's an option I don't have! I have a lot of datasets, and sometimes a set is rather short (as given). For each fit I want to have an accuracy estimate, which I'm trying to retrieve from the covariance of the parameters (few data should yield large variances, isn't it?). Now I know that this will fail if `(len(x) - order - 2.0) == 0`. What else could I do with the given data to retrieve the variances of the fit parameters?

Comment: @senderle, sorry you're definitely right, I'll scrap my answer (except for the last part so that your reference stays). Thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: No need to be sorry. I'm no expert on this by any means, so I'm glad to know that we're now on the same page. I deleted my obsolete comments and updated my answer, which I wouldn't have come to without your first insight.