# Error when trying to get covariance matrix from numpy polyfit

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to find the maxima and minima of a function that I fitted using numpy polyfit, and I also want the covariance matrix of that fit. However, that doesn't seem to work, here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from scipy.signal import argrelmax,argrelmin
a=[]
x=[]
y=[]
b=[]
with open('15.txt') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        a.append(lines[i].split())
for i in range(np.size(a)/np.size(a[0])):
    b.append(np.double(a[i][0]))
    x.append(np.double(a[i][1]))
    y.append(np.double(a[i][2]))
plx=[]
ply=[]
for i in range(np.size(x)):
    if(x[i]>0.3 and x[i]<3):
        plx.append(x[i])
        ply.append(y[i])
c,v=np.polyfit(plx,ply,30,cov=True)
f=np.poly1d(c)
x_new=np.linspace(plx[0],plx[-1],100)
y_new=f(x_new)
maxm=x_new[argrelmax(y_new)[0]]
minm=x_new[argrelmin(y_new)[0]]
print maxm
print minm
figure()
plot(x_new,y_new)
show()
```

This raises an error, at the line where I want to fit (c,v=np.polyfit(..)):
 operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (31,31) (0,)
If I leave out the cov=True, all works fine. But as soon as I try to get the covariance matrix, I get an error. What is the problem here?

Edit: full error traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Documents\Measurements\lab3.py in <module>()
     20                 plx.append(x[i])
     21                 ply.append(y[i])
---> 22 c,v=np.polyfit(plx,ply,30,cov=True)
     23 print v
     24 f=np.poly1d(c)

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.pyc in polyfit(x, y, deg, rco
nd, full, w, cov)
    599         fac = resids / (len(x) - order - 2.0)
    600         if y.ndim == 1:
--> 601             return c, Vbase * fac
    602         else:
    603             return c, Vbase[:,:, NX.newaxis] * fac

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (31,31) (0,)
```

Comment: please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: print "c" when you run it with `cov = False` or plot your input data along with the fit and tell us what you find, please. I doubt that it actually fits successfully.

Comment: Did you check `plx` and `ply` before the fit to exclude _crap in => crap out_?

Comment: Added the traceback. The plot does show a successful fit, it shows a polynomial similar to the data obtained, all looks fine on that front. I don't quite get what you mean by checking plx and ply? I excluded some crappy data from the beginning and end of the original data before fitting, if you mean that.

Comment: Show us what `plx` and `ply` are. What are their lengths and contents?

Comment: Both are huge lists, both have 1130 elements. The elements in them range from about 0 to 3.5 for both. "Random" floats.They have more or less periodic peaks, but are noisy, so therefore I want to fit them.

Comment: `numpy.polyfit` has some interesting features along the way to a covariance matrix. I also had an [issue on that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27254054/2460374) which might help you to dive into the numpy function for a better understanding. I wonder at which point in the covariance matrix calculation inside `numpy.polyfit` the problem occurs. In the end, either `Vbase` or `fac` is skrewed, I think, but I still don't know why as the number of degrees of freedom seems to be sufficiently large...